# animating mobile nav with fixed positioning

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have a top nav that is fixed so when the user scrolls through a lot of content the nav sticks like fixed positioning is supposed to do. This works, however for the mobile version of the page I need an additional nav to slide out from the left and fill the screen. I also need the entire website to move to the right at the same time the additional nav slides in. Right now the fixed top nav will not move since its fixed. I could change it positioning onClick to either relative or absolute, but if you are further down on the page looking at content the main nav will disappear onClick because its no longer fixed.

Heres the Jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vXrEm/1/

Again all I really want is the main nav to slide to the right with the rest of the content and for it to work and look like its in the same position regardless of how far down on the page you are.

```
$('.hitME').click(function () {
        if (!$('.siteContainer').hasClass('clicked')) {
            $('.mobileNav').stop().animate({ right: "0px" }, 450);

            //Below code will move the entire container but not the .nav div because it is fixed positioning
            $('.siteContainer').stop().animate({ left: "100%" }, 450);

            $('.siteContainer').addClass('clicked');
        } else if ($('.siteContainer').hasClass('clicked')) {
            $('.mobileNav').animate({ right: "100%" });

            //Below code will move the entire container but not the .nav div because it is fixed positioning
            $('.siteContainer').stop().animate({ left: "0px" }, 450);

            $('.siteContainer').removeClass('clicked');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting .nav in another fixed container and made the .nav position absolute and it works ...incase anyone cares > http://jsfiddle.net/vXrEm/2/

```
 $('.siteContainer, .nav').stop().animate({ left: "100%" }, 450);
```